# Use selenium-objective-c framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, selenium

I want to set up some tests that use the [Selenium Objective-C](https://github.com/appium/selenium-objective-c) framework. This would enable me to hook into [Appium](http://appium.io/) whilst at the same time writing acceptance tests in the same language that I write the app in.

After downloading and adding the framework to my project, I added a test target, imported the framework and ran the tests. I got expected type errors around `NSPoint`, `NSSize`, etc. which are all contained in the library.

After some investigation I realised that Selenium Objective-C uses the Mac OS version of `Foundation.framework` which contains the classes `NSPoint`, `NSSize`, etc. However, my app is an iOS app, so in `Foundation.framework` I have `CGPoint`, `CGSize`, etc...

My question is, has anyone been able to use Selenium Objective-C? If so, how did you achieve this?

Environment: Xcode 5, iOS Simulator 7.0 iPad.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I ended up using Java. The community as a whole seems to support the java selenium framework very well - I was pretty pleased with the results / help I got with it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you saw those issues is that the Selenium-Objective-C project used to for Mac only. In the Mac libraries NSPoint replaces CGPoint, CGSize -> NSSize

It wasn't all that much work to make it work for both, so I just checked in support for building for iOS.

https://github.com/appium/selenium-objective-c/commit/c27a5faf266719c87eda502718c90e350aba931e